# MongoDB $project match anything after level of nesting

Tags: mongodb

A Mongo Document exists as follows:

```
{ 
    "trip_details" : {
                "daily" : {
                        "17" : {
                                "total_cancelled_trips" : {
                                  "value": 2,
                                  "journey_id": ["LYX12345879","LY1234XYZS9"]
                                },
                                "<any_field>" : {
                                  "value": 66,
                                  "journey_id": ["LYJOURNEY1", "LYJOURNEY2"]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "monthly" : {
                        "6" : {
                                "total_cancelled_trips" : {
                                  "value": 6,
                                  "journey_id": ["LYX12345879","LY1234XYZS9", "LY1234XYZS6", "LY1234XYZS8", "LY1234XYZS7", "LY1234XYZS5"]
                                },
                                "<any_field>" : {
                                  "value": 626,
                                  "journey_id": ["LYJOURNEY1", "LYJOURNEY2", "LY1234XYZS6","LY1234XYZS7","LY1234XYZS6"]
                                }
                        }
                },
        }
}
```

I need to fetch it from MongoDB, project it in a required way, and send it to a service.

I need to fetch it and project like as follows:

```
{ 
    "trip_details" : {
                "daily" : {
                        "17" : {
                                "total_cancelled_trips" : 2,
                                "<any_field>" : 66
                         }
                 "monthly" : {
                        "6" : {
                                "total_cancelled_trips" : 6,
                                "<any_field>": 626
                         }
                  }
        }
}
```

What I've found already?
We need to use $project queries.

What I do not know?
While projecting, I do not need the "journey_id" field, and I want "total_cancelled_trips" to have value as 2 and not object.

The problem is inner structure of `trip_details.daily.17` can have any field inside, and I should map <any_field>.value as <any_field>. I am stuck with projecting <any_field>

- <any_field> is used to represent that it is abstracted and can be any string, but it will for sure have a `value` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require some data structure manipulation, it's a little tricky but here's an example of how to achieve this using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            //match your documents
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            trip_details: {
                daily: {
                    $arrayToObject: {
                        $map: {
                            input: {$objectToArray: "$trip_details.daily"},
                            as: "daily",
                            in: {
                                k: "$$daily.k",
                                v: {
                                    $arrayToObject: {
                                        $map: {
                                            input: {$objectToArray: "$$daily.v"},
                                            as: "field",
                                            in: {k: "$$field.k", v: "$$field.v.value"}
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                monthly: {
                    $arrayToObject: {
                        $map: {
                            input: {$objectToArray: "$trip_details.monthly"},
                            as: "monthly",
                            in: {
                                k: "$$monthly.k",
                                v : {
                                    $arrayToObject: {
                                        $map: {
                                            input: {$objectToArray: "$$monthly.v"},
                                            as: "field",
                                            in: {k: "$$field.k", v: "$$field.v.value"}
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

EDIT:

With hard coded options:

```
{
    $project: {
        trip_details: {
            daily: {
                "17": {
                    $arrayToObject: {
                        $map: {
                            input: {$objectToArray: "$trip_details.daily.17"},
                            as: "field",
                            in: {k: "$$field.k", v: "$$field.v.value"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            monthly: {
                "6": {
                    $arrayToObject: {
                        $map: {
                            input: {$objectToArray: "$trip_details.monthly.6"},
                            as: "field",
                            in: {k: "$$field.k", v: "$$field.v.value"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, there is no way like

`{$project: { 'trip_details.daily.17.*.value': 'trip_details.daily.17.*'}}`"

Just curious?

Comment: It's possible to do it only for 17 and 6 i choose the generic way (which is also more complicated) because i just assumed you'll come and say what if i want more days.

Comment: No, assume, programmatically, I know the key of 17 or 6. In that case, can we do the above like in my comment?

Comment: No, not like your comment. you will still need some structure manipulation to achieve the required output.

Comment: Can you make a new answer on how to do that?